# Did the members of Led Zeppelin have "known" nicknames?

Tags: led-zeppelin

I've heard and read (online) many different "Nickname" references for the members of Zeppelin, but I question the accuracy of these sources. I thought I'd ask the experts.

Comment: Did you even bother googling this? You don't even provide these nicknames anyway, so we're supposed to guess which nicknames you're talking about. Perhaps [Percy](http://www.geocities.ws/babyjustrock/insiders/percy.html)? [Bonzo](http://forums.ledzeppelin.com/index.php?/topic/11496-nicknames/)?

Comment: @BCdotWEB, funny thing is google brought me here, on this question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The book *Hammer of the Gods* by Steven Davis records a few of the nicknames that members of Led Zeppelin had for each other.

- Bonzo - John Bonham, due to his wild-man nature
- Percy - Robert Plant, for his high voice and effeminate mannerisms
- Led Wallet - Jimmy Page, for his tightness in spending money
- Jonesy - John Paul Jones most likely derived from his last name

Answer (score 2):

Over here in England there used to be a famous TV gardener called Percy Thrower and I recall reading somewhere the nick name derived from an in-joke among the band about watching our own Plant grow and develop.I would think because of this the name came about earlier on in Zeppelins career as grow and develop he did and as we all know he "blossomed" into a golden God.